# My website load on bottom on start

Tags: javascript, html

Problem is that my html website load on bottom of the webpage, the problem is with JavaScript probably.  I tried script from other Question, but it's not working. My website is http://pracowniamiejska.url.ph

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post more relevant code here? I think not a lot of people is interested in following links they don't know.

Comment: The *real* problem is that your form gets focused, fix that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Me neither :p Trust in the Force, and use the Antivirus! XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Carpetsmoker hit the nail on the head:

Your contact form has an input with `autofocus`. Focusing an element (be it through this `autofocus` attribute, through JavaScript `.focus()`, or even just tabbing to it with the keyboard) implies scrolling the element into the view, and in your case that means scrolling the page to the bottom.

Remove the `autofocus` attribute. Is it improperly used here.

Comment: @PatrickHofman This answer does not belong to me - it's Carpetsmoker who answered the question in a comment on the question, I'm simply transcribing it (and fleshing it out slightly) as an answer. Since it's not my answer, it would be wrong to claim credit for it. Therefore, CW.